# How do I remove the <opt> tag in XML::Simple output?

Tags: ruby, xml, perl

I'm creating an XML file using Perl and [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Simple) module. I successfully create the XML file, but the problem is I am having `<opt> </opt>` tag for each my tags. I am looking for any option which we can aviod the `<opt> </opt>` tag. I can't do the post-processing to remove the  tag. because the file size is huge.

Example :

```
<opt>
  <person firstname="Joe" lastname="Smith">
    <email>joe@smith.com</email>
    <email>jsmith@yahoo.com</email>
  </person>
  <person firstname="Bob" lastname="Smith">
    <email>bob@smith.com</email>
  </person>
</opt>
```

and I am looking for  (without `<opt>` tag):

```
  <person firstname="Joe" lastname="Smith">
    <email>joe@smith.com</email>
    <email>jsmith@yahoo.com</email>
  </person>
  <person firstname="Bob" lastname="Smith">
    <email>bob@smith.com</email>
  </person>
```

Comment: If opt is your root node, the result is invalid XML, which must have a single root node.

Comment: actually i have changed rootname

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The  tag is the root element of the XML generated from the user-supplied data-structure. 
From the [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::Simple) documentation -

> **RootName => 'string' # out - handy**
>
> By default, when XMLout() generates
>   XML, the root element will be named
>   'opt'. This option allows you to
>   specify an alternative name.
>
> Specifying either undef or the empty
>   string for the RootName option will
>   produce XML with no root elements. In
>   most cases the resulting XML fragment
>   will not be 'well formed' and
>   therefore could not be read back in by
>   XMLin(). Nevertheless, the option has
>   been found to be useful in certain
>   circumstances.

To set the root element to blank just pass RootName as 'undef' to XMLout, for eg.

```
use XML::Simple;

my $xml = XMLout($hashref, RootName => undef);
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across this answer when searching for the same info (read, parse, modify, and output xml, fix the `<opt>` root tag) but in Ruby.

FYI, the root node can also be removed or named in the [Ruby version](http://xml-simple.rubyforge.org/) of the library:

```
require 'xmlsimple' # gem install xml-simple
data = XmlSimple.xml_in(filename)  # read data from filename
# Parse data as needed, then output:
XmlSimple.xml_out(data, { 'RootName' => nil })     # Remove root element
XmlSimple.xml_out(data, { 'RootName' => 'html' })  # Change root <opt> to <html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer did not work for me.  What you can do is:

```
my $xml = XML::Simple->new(KeepRoot=>0);
print $xml->XMLout($YourVariable);
```

That said, a valid XML document should have a root.  If what you want to do is name your root node, you can do this:

```
print $xml->XMLout({'RootNodeName' => {'ChildNode'=>[@ArrayOfThings]}});
```